# Is there any Open-Source project hosting that allows to programmatically upload distribution?

Tags: python, open-source, uploading, project-hosting

I develop open-source project in Python and I want it to be easy accessible for Windows users. So for each new source revision I need to generate new windows executable distribution with [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and upload it as a downloadable artifact for project users.

I'd rather not do it each time manually but instead I would like to write some type of script that will do both things (generation, upload) in single command, fully programically.

So the question is: are there any Open Source project hostings that provide simple API to make operations like uploading new version of distribution?

Currently I'm using Google Code but it doesn't support that feature (I expected it to be supported as [Google Data Api Service](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html) but it isn't). I don't really know too much about other hostings - that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Code does support it perfectly well: http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ScriptedUploads

Most other such sites do in a similar way; on one project on SourceForge, for example, I have a release script which [uploads a file to the release system by FTP](http://portableapps.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/portableapps/launcher/file/8e5505c34bf2/Other/Source/make_release#l117).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it! I from some reason couldn't find this information. But it's in fact possible in Google Code.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [the GitHub Downloads API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/downloads/) or, if it's something suitable for packaging, then look at [PyPI, the Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi)

Comment: Thanks. I will check out first link, possibly it's exactly what I need. About second part - see my response under Sven Marnach's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Distutils](http://docs.python.org//distutils/index.html) that come with Python [support uploading](http://docs.python.org//distutils/uploading.html) to the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But that's not what I'm expecting. I want to have my project easily accessible for Windows non technical users not having installed python at all (and definitely don't knowing how to use distutils and similar tools). So uploading Windows-specific distribution to hosting service is the only option.

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk:  The users wouldn't have to cope with distutils at all, but they would need a Python installation.